# How to let a div become visible when the bar is full [JS]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my name is Daniel and i'm making a drinking game for school, I want to let a div to become visible when the bar is full (so you know when the bar is full and you win the game), but i have no idea how to do this...

Could you help me out?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style="display: none;" id="hiddenText">
<div id="bar" class="animated bounceInUp">
</div>
</div>
```

**CCS:**

```
#bar {
  background-color: #F8F8F8 ;
  width: 340px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
#bar > div {
    margin-top: 30px;
  max-width: 334px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 16px;
  background: #9d3349;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  left: 3px;
  transition: width 500ms;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var jumpsize = 2.77, // %
  body = $("body");
(container = $("#bar")), (bar = container.children("div")), (topcnt = function(
  px
) {
  return 100 * px / container.width();
}), (set = function(pcnt) {
  bar.css({ width: pcnt + "%" });
});

body
  .on("click", ".card1, .card2, .card3, .card4", function() {
    set(topcnt(bar.width()) + jumpsize);
  });

set(0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason its not working is because u forgot to put the if statement in the function u run on click. So the if statement only runs once. and on first load it will result in false. To fix your code move the if statement in your Body.onclick.

Next time it would be smart to include the full javascript that is relative to the function.

By looking at the online code i was able to find the issue.

Hope this resolves your issues.

~Yannick

Answer (score 0):

When you hit your target you need to remove the CSS styling of Display = none.

W3 schools page here for some helpful info to help you learn some more.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp

The line below inserted when you reach your goal to display should make the bar appear.

```
document.getElementById("hiddenText").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Thats not what im looking for... i'll link you to the website so you get a better view of what im making... http://20162.hosts.ma-cloud.nl/beerlinapp/ ..click on the cards to fill the bar, but i want something to happen when the bar is full

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery so quicker will be:

```
$('#hiddenText').show();
```

Edit: 
sooo

```
if($('#bar').children('div').width() >= 334){
$('#hiddenText').show();
}
```

As You can see the div with progress bar can have max od 334 px. Check if it has it and if yes then show the text. Put this in that click event

Comment: Thats not what im looking for... i'll link you to the website so you get a better view of what im making... http://20162.hosts.ma-cloud.nl/beerlinapp/ ..click on the cards to fill the bar, but i want something to happen when the bar is full

Comment: I made this now:     <div class="test1" id="hiddenText5" style="display: none;"> This needs to show up when the bar is full</div> and if($('#bar').children('div').width() >= 334){
$('#hiddenText5').show();
}
it doesn't work...

Comment: To be honest now i dont know which div You want to show?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want this, but try this:

```js
var jumpsize = 2.77, // %
    width = 0,
  body = $("body");
(container = $("#bar")), (bar = container.children("div")), (topcnt = function(
  px
) {
  return 100 * px / container.width();
}), (set = function(pcnt) {
  bar.css({ width: pcnt + "%" });
  if(pcnt >= 100) {$('#hiddenText').show();}
});

body
  .on("click", ".card1, .card2, .card3, .card4", function() {
    width += jumpsize;
    set(topcnt(width));
  });

set(0);
```

```css
#bar {
  background-color: #F8F8F8 ;
  width: 340px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
#bar > div {
    margin-top: 30px;
  max-width: 334px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 16px;
  background: #9d3349;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  left: 3px;
  transition: width 500ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12" style="display: none;" id="hiddenText">
<div id="bar" class="animated bounceInUp">
  <div></div>
</div>
</div>
<button class="card1">click me</button>
```

Comment: Thats not what im looking for... i'll link you to the website so you get a better view of what im making... http://20162.hosts.ma-cloud.nl/beerlinapp/ ..click on the cards to fill the bar, but i want something to happen when the bar is full

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you're overcomplicating things a little bit with the percentage calculations. I would just add a variable for the width of the bar that starts at 0 and increase this with the jumpsize on every click. Once this new variable goes over or equals 100 you show the hidden div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12" id="hiddenText">
  <div id="bar" class="animated bounceInUp">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="button">Click me</button>
<div id="showOnComplete">Show me when the bar is full!</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#bar {
  width: 340px;
  height: 24px;
  padding: 4px 3px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

#bar > div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: #9d3349;
  transition: width 500ms;
}

#button {
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
}

#showOnComplete {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
(function($) {
  var jumpSize = 20, //increased this for the fiddle, so we don't have to click as often
      barWidth = 0,
      $bar,
      $showOnComplete;

  $(function() {
    $bar = $("#bar").children("div");
    $showOnComplete = $("#showOnComplete");

    $(document).on("click", "#button", function() {
      barWidth += jumpSize;
      $bar.width(barWidth + "%");
      if (barWidth >= 100) $showOnComplete.show(); //optionally add a setTimeout of 500 here to account for the final transition of the bar
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

I've made a fiddle for it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cqjh9aza/4/).

Comment: This also makes it easier to determine the jumpsize. If you want the div to be shown after 20 clicks, the jumpsize would simply be 100/20 = 5.